# Ways to say "Download" and "Upload"

Tags: tradução-inglês, diferenças-transatlânticas

talking about these

1.- Descarregar
2.- Transferir
3.- Fazer download

The opposite:

1.- Carregar
2.- Transferir
3.- Fazer upload

I would like to know which are most used in Brasil and in Portugal. And which ones do you use to say "Downloaded" and "Uploaded". For example: "Descarregado" and "Carregado".

Answer (score 6):

I believe these are the most common ways:

**To download**

BRPT: Baixar / Fazer download
(baixado / o download está concluído)

EUPT: Descarregar / Fazer download
(descarregado / o download foi concluído/feito)

**To upload**

BRPT: Transferir / Enviar / Fazer upload
(transferido/ o upload foi concluído/feito)

EUPT: Carregar / Fazer upload
(carregado/ o upload foi concluído/feito)

Comment: Sempre usei "subir" para *upload*.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, in Brazil (not sure about other Portuguese speaking countries) it is very common to use the words Download and Upload just like this, although "baixado" and "enviado" were used more often in the past.

Comment: Se não usar o it dois vezes como sujeito, as frases não fazem sentido...

Comment: Luiz, feel free to roll back to your original phrasing if you don't like my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Esse é mais um exemplo que rechaça a suposta regra que diz para não usar um termo em inglês quando houver um equivalente em português. Sem âncoras contextuais ou cotextuais, as palavras "carregar" e "descarregar" não fazem tanto sentido quanto fariam os termos em inglês "upload" e "download". Prefiro manter os termos em inglês para esse caso.

Comment: Olá, Vera, minhas boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE. Obrigado pela contribuição, mas note que a pergunta é "quais as traduções mais usadas no Brasil e em Portugal", e sua resposta é na verdade um comentário, pois não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação o bastante](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), você poderá deixar comentários em postagens.